# GET request ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol

Tags: ssl, curl

I have a problem dealing with an upgrade of an application doing GET request to a remote server.

First thing first : a functional example of a GET done by the **old** version, and as expected it works

```
curl -k -vvvvv https://mywebsite.com/mywonderfulwebsite/mypage.php

*   Trying 192.168.0.70...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mywebsite.com (192.168.0.70) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / AES128-SHA
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=MYWEBSITE.COM
*  start date: Mar 24 10:20:51 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 24 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  issuer: CN=MYWEBSITE.COM
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET /mywonderfulwebsite/mypage.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: mywebsite.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
....... and here the content of the page.....
```

And now from the new version, it doesn't work

```
curl -vvvvv https://mywebsite.com/mywonderfulwebsite/mypage.php
*   Trying 192.168.0.70:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mywebsite.com (192.168.0.70) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, protocol version (582):
* error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
```

So I think it was from the TLS version, no problem let's force it :

```
curl --tlsv1.0 -vvvvv https://mywebsite.com/mywonderfulwebsite/mypage.php

*   Trying 192.168.0.70:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mywebsite.com (192.168.0.70) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, protocol version (582):
* error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
```

and it's a fail.

I've tried adding the certificates from the remote website, and I have the same answer.

I've looked at a request using openssl client :

```
# openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.com:443 -tls1
CONNECTED(00000003)
139820362433856:error:141E70BF:SSL routines:tls_construct_client_hello:no protocols available:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1112:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 7 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

And now I'm playing with versions and requests and I have no clue where I should check.
Do you know how I could troubleshoot my problem ?

Comment: It looks like you are using a version of OpenSSL either compiled oddly (to remove TLS1.0) or configured somewhere to disable TLS1.0 (including SECLEVEL>=3 and/or SuiteB). What kind of system are you on (Linux? which? other Unix? MacOS? ChromeOS? Android? Windows?), exactly which program files are you running and where did they come from (package manager with standard repo(s), other repo, self-built, a friend or coworker, some website)? Is envvar OPENSSL_CONF set? If not, use `openssl version -d` to find your config file and see if it has any global settings.

Comment: (Although checking certs correctly is a good thing in general, your problem was&is not at all cert-related so it is expected that fixing the certs has no effect on it.)

Comment: You are right. It was definitely TSL related, a problem with the minimal TLS version. On Debian Buster openssl is configured to forbid the usage if TLS < 1.2

I'll explain it in my answer to the question

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the solution : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level

Late openssl package is configured to forbid the usage of TLS < 1.2 however, the first curl request shows a communication using TLS 1.0

So in debian Buster openssl package was too new

```
dpkg -l | grep openssl
ii  openssl                       1.1.1d-0+deb10u7
```

**I didn't have to downgrade Openssl**

Edit /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

add in the beginning of the file

```
openssl_conf = default_conf
```

And this to the end of the file

```
[ default_conf ]

ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]

system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

Changing the configuration allow the usage of minimal version of TSL starting TSL 1.0 and more, so from now I can request my legacy partner.

Comment: You're a freaking life saver man! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**For centOS users.**

My solution is to lower the protocol to be used to the minimum level.

```
/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensslcnf.config

MinProtocol = TLSv1.0
```

It worked, I hope it helps you.
Greetings.